# how to find keycodes for Aterm backspace, and deletekey

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal-emulator

I downloaded compiled, and installed aterm 1.0.1. and I cannot get the backspace or delete keys to work. I've tried everything I've found on the net about it.

```
aterm*backspacekey: \010
aterm*deletekey: \177

aterm*backspacekey: ^?
```

I even recompiled it with the options.

```
--disable-backspace-key
    disable any handling of the backspace key by us - let the X server
    do it
--disable-delete-key
    disable any handling of the delete key by us - let the X server
    do it
```

when I reinstall it, then fire it up .. type something in the term then press the backspace or delete key either way I have it built, it will move forward ... when I've tryed other "key codes" it will just type them to the screen.

according to [this](http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard.html) with what little I've read so far.

```
At any rate, first find out whether the terminfo entry for xterm is in
accordance with your xterm settings: infocmp | grep kbs
should return a line which includes kbs=\177. This means DEL (or ^?)
is mapped to the backspace key, which is what we want.
```

this is what I get.

```
$infocmp | grep kbs

kNXT=\E[6;2~, kPRV=\E[5;2~, kRIT=\E[1;2C, kb2=\EOE, kbs=^H,
```

I am using BASH sh. Void Linux, i3 wm.

thanks

Comment: What you *actually* get can usually be *seen* by running `cat -v` and pressing control+V before each special character.  Compare that with the result from `stty -a` (the `erase` value).  If those do not match against the `kbs` value, you can have problems, but "will move forward" doesn't give much insight.

Comment: move forward -- like hitting the space bar in place of the backspace- or the backspace is mimicing the spacebar when pressing it, only three spaces then it stops. I hope that clearifies. @ThomasDickey

Comment: issued cat -v Ctrl+V then backspace key : received ^? 
issused cat -v Ctrl+V then delete key: received ^[[3~
stty -a : results says 'erase = ^?'
@ThomasDickey

Comment: @ThomasDickey 
added this to Xdefaults aterm*backspacekey:  ^? 
when I hit the backspace key it still mimics the spacebar and the prompt will either jump down a line moving over to the right, or not at times, depending on what value is added to the aterm*backspace: "value"